# open and close vlc player automatically

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to open and close the vlc player automatically in a Lubuntu VMware. I have tried a shell script code like:

```
   vlc rtmp:/<ip addres>/code
   sleep(5)
   exit 0 or vlc:quit
```

It opens the vlc player and start it but does not go for the second line and therefore, can not close it.

So, please let me know how can I fix it.

Comment: Try `timeout 5 vlc ...`

Comment: Thank you very much it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just writing up my comment. You can use:

```
timeout 5 vlc rtmp:/<ip addres>/code
```